# Проблема с четкостью изображения в canvas

Tags: javascript, html5, canvas

Впервые использую canvas. При загрузке туда изображения оно получается размытым. Как добиться чтоб оно выглядело также четко как оригинал?

```
<img src="http://afriendinparis.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/Vue_Paris.jpg" width=200><br>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>

let elem = document.getElementById("canvas")
let ctx = elem.getContext('2d')
let pic = new Image()
pic.src = "http://afriendinparis.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/Vue_Paris.jpg"
let k = (pic.width/pic.height)/17
let width = (pic.width*k).toFixed(0),
    height = (pic.height*k).toFixed(0)
pic.onload = function() {
  /* ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = false; */
  ctx.drawImage(pic, 0, 0, width, height);
}
```

Код на https://jsfiddle.net/shegby/L9d61hxf/

Comment: если больше сделать, то все норм, вроде

Comment: даже если сделать 1:1 все равно не то. нашел целый пост на эту тему на хабре https://habr.com/post/252175/